# How can I get the text only (no tags) from a HTML document?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a HTML page, and I want the text only (all text nodes).

#### Example HTML

```
<span>hello <strong>sir</strong></span>
```

#### Desired Output

```
hello sir
```

Comment: Voting to close... far too vague.

Comment: I want the entire web page content to be input to my program,so how do I get the web page content as plain text.clear??

Comment: I want the current web page to displayed as plain text because this text I am using as input to an other program .It would be very helpful  if that is done  using JavaScript

Comment: yes exactly ,No html tags I want only the content .for ex what ever I see on the web page (the text) is needed

Comment: for ex : my output is like this <b>google</b> but I want only google not the tags

Comment: @Anusha I've updated your question so it is clearer.

Answer (score 29):

Assuming you only want children of `body` element...

#### Example HTML

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  a <div>b<span>c</span></div>
</body></html>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var body = document.body;
var textContent = body.textContent || body.innerText;

console.log(textContent);  //   a bc
```

You need to check for `textContent` because our good friend IE uses `innerText` instead.

It is much easier if you have a library such as [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/4n42F/), i.e. `$('body').text()`.

Also, it can be achieved on the server side, such as [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) in PHP. However, if you only wanted the `body` element, you'd need to drill down to it using a DOM parser such as [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you are trying to get the html for the page your JS is residing on

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
var result = '';
for(var k in elems)
    result += elems[k].innerHTML || '';
alert(result);
```

Comment: `innerHTML` contains HTML tags.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure I completely understand but if you want the markup for the current page then I guess you could make an Ajax request against the current page and use that:

```
$.get("/current-page-name", function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/CAWkx/

Comment: I want the current web page to displayed as plain text because this text I am using as input to an other program .It would be very helpful if that is done using JavaScript