# Simple Screen Scraping using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping

I have been playing with the idea of using a simple screen-scraper using jQuery and I am wondering if the following is possible.

I have simple HTML page and am making an attempt (if this is possible) to grab the contents of all of the list items from another page, like so:

**Main Page:**

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("[URL to other page]",
  function(data){

    //Iterate through the <li> inside of the URL's data
    $.each(data.items, function(item){
      $("<li/>").value().appendTo("#data");
    });

  });
});
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<html>
    <body>
       <div id='data'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Other Page:**

```
//Html
<body>
    <p><b>Items to Scrape</b></p>   
    <ul>
        <li>I want to scrape what is here</li>
        <li>and what is here</li>
        <li>and here as well</li>
        <li>and append it in the main page</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**So, is it possible using jQuery to pull all of the list item contents from an external page and append them inside of a div?**

Comment: It's also possible to get the text (without tags) of the current page in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321739/how-can-i-get-the-text-only-no-tags-from-a-html-document

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `$.ajax` to load the other page into a variable, then create a temporary element and use `.html()` to set the contents to the value returned. Loop through the  element's children of nodeType 1 and keep their first children's nodeValues. If the external page is not on your web server you will need to proxy the file with your own web server.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/thePageToScrape.html",
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(data) {
          var elements = $("<div>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
          for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
               var theText = elements[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
               // Do something here
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail on what "proxy the file" means?

Comment: @AdamYoungers: “Proxy the file” is pretty much a full description. Make a request to your own server; make your own server fetch the requested page from the target. In Nginx, it would be a `proxy_pass`. If you wanted to do it in PHP, you could use `<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['proxy']); ?>`.

Comment: Make sure to whitelist the Content-Type of the proxied resources, though; add and check for a custom header indicating XHR; avoid making an open proxy; make use of CORS when possible, and put the proxy on a different domain.

Answer (score 9):

Simple scraping with jQuery...

```
// Get HTML from page
$.get( 'http://example.com/', function( html ) {

    // Loop through elements you want to scrape content from
    $(html).find("ul").find("li").each( function(){

        var text = $(this).text();
        // Do something with content

    } )

} );
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$.get("/path/to/other/page",function(data){
  $('#data').append($('li',data));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Fareesh what would be the difference between these two?

``.append($('li',data))``

and

``.append(data) ``

Answer (score 6):

If this is for the same domain then no problem - the jQuery solution is good.

But otherwise you can't access content from an arbitrary website because this is considered a security risk. See [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

There are of course server side workarounds such as a web proxy or [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control).
Of if you're lucky they will support jsonp.

But if you want a client side solution to work with an arbitrary website and web browser then you are out of luck. There is a [proposal to relax this policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), but this won't effect current web browsers.

Comment: There are many ways to access content outside your domain.  For example:

  • jsonp
  • proxy

Comment: Same Origin Policy is not an issue on Safari and a properly initialized Chrome

Comment: @LukeMcneice can u explain how same origin policy is not an in safari and chrome? also what does it mean properly initialized?

Comment: @hnovick - my post is addressing client side solutions for an arbitrary webpage. Have added acknowledgment of solutions for specific cases.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider pjscrape:

http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/

It allows you to do this from the command-line, using javascript and jQuery. It does this by using PhantomJS, which is a headless webkit browser (it has no window, and it exists only for your script's usage, so you can load complex websites that use AJAX and it will work just as if it were a real browser).

The examples are self-explanatory and I believe this works on all platforms (including Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Use YQL or Yahoo pipes to make the cross domain request for the raw page html content. The yahoo pipe or YQL query will spit this back as a JSON that can be processed by jquery to extract and display the required data.

On the downside: YQL and Yahoo pipes OBEY the robots.txt file for the target domain
and if the page is to long the Yahoo Pipes regex commands will not run.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you will hit the CORS issue with requests in many cases.
From [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86) try to resolve CORS issue.

```
var name = "kk";
var url = "http://anyorigin.com/go?url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://www.yoursite.xyz/") + name + "&callback=?";
$.get(url, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```