# Dynamically web scrape tables for a CMS

Tags: javascript, python, drupal, web-scraping, html-table

Does anyone have suggestions as to how I could scrape a table that updates daily from a website when I do not have access to server side scripting? Specifically, I am using a CMS - Drupal - and do not have access to the hosting server, nor can I create or modify modules. I believe this rules out the use of Python, PHP, etc..

Is there any way to scrape a website's HTML, parse the table, and display its data (or display the table in its entirety) on my webpage using just Javascript? I've read about Node.js and other scripts that rely on languages like PHP, but as I said, I don't believe I can run these.

Any suggestions or leads would be most helpful.. I am not the most educated on how these functions run.

**Edit ---** I should have mentioned that it has the same domain.. The dynamically updated content is on a sub directory that I cannot access. I suppose this sounds a bit silly, but this is the situation that I am in.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cannot access external sites from javascript.

However, if the site is in the same domain, I guess you could adapt the code presented in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667880/simple-screen-scraping-using-jquery).

Comment: I should have mentioned that it has the same domain.. The dynamically updated content is on a sub directory that I cannot access. I suppose this sounds a bit silly, but this is the situation that I am in.