# javascript which copy content which is into a html div into another page created by me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need something written in javascript or jquery that copy a content of a page (for example there is a page with a html table in which there are lot of fields about the weather in my city, i'd like to copy the fields (morning: 10°C, afternoon: 15°C, evening: 11°C), in a web page i'll create).
Obviusly that fields have to be reloaded every X minutes (for example 30 minutes) because the fields with the weather are reloaded every X minutes in their database.

I hope my english is not to much bad, so you could help me in this problem.
Thank yall!

Comment: Are you asking how to copy content from somebody else's page into your own?

Comment: yes only inputs like <div class="first_class">10°C</div>.. exactly "10°C"... etc.. it's possible!?

Comment: I don't really support the idea of nicking stuff from somebody else's page, both because it seems a bit dishonest and because from a practical point of view your code would probably break if they decide to change their layout. If weather data is what you are looking for why not find a weather service that provides an API so that you can retrieve the data directly? See this question: [best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363052/best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are asking about is [web Scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

There is a Javascript framework to handle this called [PJScrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/), there may be others and a G* search should help you.

There is also a question regarding simple scraping here on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667880/simple-screen-scraping-using-jquery).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with JavaScript because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You need to download this page with PHP and then parse your values. You can use for example [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to work with downloaded page like with JavaScript (there are examples on their site so i dont append example code here)...