# How to get an attribute of an image from another document/link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, getattribute

I am currently using this Javascript code to change the `src` of IMAGE1 (id="index_thumbnail") with the `src` of IMAGE2 (id="coverphoto2"):

`document.getElementById('index_thumbnail').setAttribute('src',getvalue=document.getElementById('coverphoto2').getAttribute('src'))`

It works only if both IMAGE1 and IMAGE2 are on the same webpage. The problem is that I want to get the `src` of IMAGE2 which is found on **another** webpage. How do I do this without altering much code? Thanks!

---

Edit: I want the source of the link to be from a posts `{Permalink}` on tumblr.

Comment: This wouldn't be possible due to security issues.

Comment: You might be able to do this with some screen-scraping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667880/simple-screen-scraping-using-jquery, but that's quite a hack.

Comment: Pretty sure that this can't be accomplished due to the same origin policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)