# iOS: getting constantly updating information from web

Tags: javascript, ios, stream

So I've made an iPhone application that streams online radio from here: http://wvum.org/index.php/wvum/stream/

However, I'd like to also include in my app the information (it doesn't necessarily have to be in a scrolling bar like in the web player) about the song and artist. In the web player, this information is constantly acquired and updated using a JS script- however, my knowledge of JS is rather poor. I was wondering if there was a way to grab this data right from the web page that the script puts it on and include it in my application?

Comment: Learn JS. It's not hard.

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded this better. I have a working (but certainly not extensive) knowledge of JS. What I need to know is how to parse text from a website and whether the fact that the text is retrieved using a JS script changes anything.

Comment: Learn advanced JS. It's not hard. (just advanced :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to me that the JavaScript is retrieving the name of the track, but rather the server is just returning that in the HTML, so you can just parse that.

It strikes me that rather than parsing this html page, you might want to grab `7.html` from the shoutcast server. If you want name of current track, retrieve the `.pls` contents to get the URL of the server (which I determined by looking at `http://www.wvum.org/listen.pls`), and then retrieve `7.html` for information, e.g. `http://wvum.org:9010/7.html`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wvum.org:9010/7.html"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", connectionError);
        return;
    }
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"server response = %@", string);
}];
```

Not all servers respond to `7.html`, but this one does. Anyway, that HTML might be easier to parse.

Comment: You were right. I solved it with something similar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this [Simple Screen Scraping using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667880/simple-screen-scraping-using-jquery). It looks like the the song info is stored in the only `<marquee />` on the page.

Comment: How does that relate to iOS, though?