# Scraping particular data from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

My intent is to load some content/html in iframe through ajax call to different domain.
Due to same-origin policy it keeps me from extracting these content and sending to my script. 
I have read numerous articles how to workaround this problem but buttom line is that I need to have access to html file from which I am trying to extract content and this is not a case.
Do you have some idea, hack, workaround?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Do you also have access/control over the content/html which is in the iframe? Do you control both domains? This guide might be helpful: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes/.

Comment: Thnx for great article, no I do not have control on neither html in iframe nor domain on which is that html

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically a duplicate of [Simple Screen Scraping using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667880/simple-screen-scraping-using-jquery). 
Proxy the other website using php or some other means, and then you no longer have cross domain issues.