# DOM PHP - Find all possible text in a webpage (title, placeholder, ...)

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a classical HTML webpage

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Some text</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
      var text = "Hi guys !";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello guys</h1>
    <p>Some text <strong>is more important</strong></p>
    <input value="Here also is some text" placeholder="and here too">
    <a href="not here">here is some text</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to get all the text from the webpage using php.
Checking nodeType for DOMText  will forget placeholder for instance.

Is there an easy way to quickly get all the real text (meaning all english text in my case) ?

Comment: "stylesheet" is also an english word. Do you want it or not?

Comment: No, because stylesheet is a keyword and will to be displayed

Comment: I used $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc); $xpath->query('//text()') but it isignoring placeholder for instance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want children of `body` element...

Example HTML

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  a <div>b<span>c</span></div>
</body></html>
```

JavaScript

```
var body = document.body;
var textContent = body.textContent || body.innerText;

console.log(textContent);  //   a bc
```

You need to check for `textContent` because our good friend IE uses `innerText` instead.

It is much easier if you have a library such as jQuery, i.e. `$('body').text()`.

[Refre This Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321739/how-can-i-get-the-text-only-no-tags-from-a-html-document)

Comment: This is javascript, i need a server side solution in php :)

Answer (score 0):

Ref : http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Text-Between-Tags.html

```
<?php
$html='<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Some text</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
  var text = "Hi guys !";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello guys</h1>
<p>Some text <strong>is more important</strong></p>
<input value="Here also is some text" placeholder="and here too">
<a href="not here">here is some text</a>
</body>
</html>';

$content = getTextBetweenTags('body', $html);

foreach( $content as $item )
{
echo $item.'<br />';
}
function getTextBetweenTags($tag, $html, $strict=0)
{
/*** a new dom object ***/
$dom = new domDocument;

/*** load the html into the object ***/
if($strict==1)
{
    $dom->loadXML($html);
}
else
{
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
}

/*** discard white space ***/
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

/*** the tag by its tag name ***/
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagname($tag);

/*** the array to return ***/
$out = array();
foreach ($content as $item)
{
    /*** add node value to the out array ***/
    $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
}
/*** return the results ***/
return $out;
}
```

Comment: This won't return placeholder text or title for instance

Answer (score 0):

Use textContent property of DomDocument

```
<?
error_reporting(-1); 

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
echo $dom->textContent;
```

result

```
Some text
      var text = "Hi guys !";

    Hello guys
    Some text is more important
    here is some text
```

Comment: Placeholder is missing

Comment: it is param value. how distinguish  it from src, for example ?

Comment: The distinction is that this a value actually displayed on screen.